# Cannot resolve public path when trying to read barryvh/dompdf in laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, pdf, laravel-8

I deployed a laravel app to shared hosting. Then I separated the folders into two DOMAIN containing the all the other folders and public_html containing the files in the public directory. I then modified index.php file in public like this

```
  require __DIR__.'/../domain/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../domain/bootstrap/app.php';
```

The app seems to work well, except for some features like the barrydompdf that gives me the error
Cannot resolve public path
Please any idea on how I can fix this. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Could you give us the actual error text? Does it say more than "Cannot resolve public path"?

Comment: That's all that is in the error head. However it is pointing to these very peace of code in the controller  $response = $kernel->handle(

    $request = Request::capture()

)->send();         and this in the blade    $pdf = PDF::loadView('file_pdf', $data)->setPaper('a3', 'landscape');

 return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');

Comment: Is there any other modifications I was supposed to do that I have not done?

Comment: Sounds like it, but you've already passed my depth of knowledge in Laravel, so I hope you find someone with the right info!

Answer (score 19):

This is the most stupid error by DOMPDF.
To resolve this error, all you need to do is to create a public folder in project directory, Although it is of no use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved a big issue.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is submitted to DOMPDF Git already and people have found workaround of it.

**Go to this path**

> vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src

**Edit**

> ServiceProvider.php

**Search for**

> base_path('public')

**and replace it with**

> public_path()

**OR YOU CAN JUST CREATE A PUBLIC FOLDER IN YOUR CODEBASE DIRECTORY**

EDIT:
This happens when your code base has no public folder and you have separated your public folder to public_html.

Answer (score 2):

remplace

```
'public_path' => null
```

for

```
'public_path' => base_path()
```

to file path

/config/dompdf.php

you can see the same topic here

> https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cannot-resolve-public-path-dompdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Never edit the content under the vendor folder

Just add this property in your config/app.php

```php
'public_path' => public_path(),
```